# date-time equality in breezejs

Tags: entity-framework, datetime, breeze, asp.net-web-api

I am stuck with date-time equality in breezejs.

What I want to do is query data and return only the latest records that changed since my last sync.

```
...
query = query.where('ModifiedDateTime', '>=', lastSyncDate);
```

The ModifiedDateTime is a DateTime type on the dB side, and the lastSyncDate is the datetime of last sync from `new Date(Date.now())`

This works for the day but not for the time, what I wanted to do is call the `getTime()` function to get an integer to compare like described here: [Beware equality tests](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/date-time)  but I can't figure out how to do it in the where clause?

Something like

```
query = query.where(ModifiedDateTime.getTime(), '>=', lastSyncDate.getTime());
```

But obviously this is not possible, is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Browser DateTime is unlikely to be the same as server DateTime in the real world.  I think you need a way to get the server sync DateTime from the server and use that in your request. A recommendation on how to proceed depends much on how you define `lastSyncDateTime` and perhaps your willingness to supplement the client/server protocol to include sync DateTime in the server response AND dig that out on the client so you can use it in a query. The tools are there but there is nothing native in Breeze to support this.

You might have a good feature request here for out-of-the-box breeze Web API protocol enhancement. You might suggest that we extend that protocol to include the server DateTime in the response (e.g. in a custom header) AND make that available to the breeze application developer as one of the properties of the query (and save) result.

But getting ahead of myself. First step is to explain what your need for this is and how you use it.

Comment: Ward - i have a similar need. When a user of my SPA is ready to submit their final changes to the db, i need to insert the record with the server datetime, not the browser datetime. This serves as a marker for when they saved their changes. I need that datetime to stay null in the db otherwise. I could query the server just before the insert to get the datetime, but it seems like there should be a way to do it on the server itself. Possibly 'intercepting' the save in breezejs on the server. Ideas?

Comment: "Intercepting on the server" is EXACTLY what you do. I don't know what server technologies you're using. If you're using our "happy path" `ContextProvider`, [the `BeforeSaveEntity` override/delegate](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/contextprovider/#BeforeSaveEntity) is the perfect place to intervene. See